# Make a list into list of list in certain order using python

Tags: python, sorting

I have list

```
my_list= [33,29,33,87,83,138,141,145,191,191,191]
```

Now i have another list

```
split_list = [2,4,7]
```

Now I need to separate my_list values by using the values in split_list as my position value of my_list,

in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978386/subdivide-a-list-into-list-of-lists)  they have grouped the list in with 4 elements in each list using scala, like wise i want to use the number in split_list as grouping factor

like this

```
answer_list = [(33,29,33),(87,83),(138,141,145),(191,191,191)]
```

Comment: I see a requirement here, not a question.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?  As in the `answer_list` I do not see a bunch of 4 or 7 .. only 2 or 3?

Comment: I don't have clue on how to proceed it.

Comment: using my split_list as my position i have to cut my_list till that and proceed further,

like in split_list the first value is 2 ,
so now i need to cut 0,1,2 position of my_list a group it as a list likewise for 4 and 7 so on

Comment: @DeepanRaj So, still make your question clear for better understanding so that people will know what you are thinking. The input what you have shown and the output what you are referring doesn't make sense and people won't be able to understand you requirements. please make the question clearer, else it will be mentioned for closing.

Comment: @DeepanRaj dear you are still not making any sense...

Comment: What's happened to 138? As far as I can see it's the only dropped element. Judging by your provided slices, the third group should be `[138, 141, 145]`.

Comment: yes izaak .. my bad..missed that number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension by slightly adjusting the `split_list`:

```
>>> my_list= [33,29,33,87,83,138,141,145,191,191,191]
>>> split_list = [2,4,7]
>>> split_list = [-1] + split_list + [len(my_list)]
>>> [tuple(my_list[split_list[i]+1:split_list[i+1]+1]) for i in range(len(split_list)-1)]
[(33, 29, 33), (87, 83), (138, 141, 145), (191, 191, 191)]
```

If the indices were instead the index of the item *before which* the slice occurred, you could have slightly nicer code:

```
>>> my_list= [33,29,33,87,83,138,141,145,191,191,191]
>>> split_list = [2,4,7]
>>> split_list = [i + 1 for i in split_list] # To change the list to [3,5,8]
>>> split_list = [None] + split_list + [None]
>>> [tuple(my_list[split_list[i]:split_list[i+1]]) for i in range(len(split_list)-1)]
[(33, 29, 33), (87, 83), (138, 141, 145), (191, 191, 191)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Working, though not very elegant:

```
first = 0
answer_list = []
for last in split_list:
    answer_list.append(my_list[first:last+1])
    first = last+1
answer_list.append(my_list[first:])
```

Comment: I don't believe this accounts for the last group (`191,191,191`). If you add `answer_list.append(my_list[first:])` after the for loop it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use use list slicing:

```
my_list= [33,29,33,87,83,138,141,145,191,191,191]
split_list= [2,4,7]

split_list.append(len(my_list)-1)
answer_list = []
prev = 0
for i in split_list :
    answer_list.append(tuple(my_list[prev:i+1]))
    prev = i+1
print(answer_list)
```

output : `[(33, 29, 33), (87, 83), (138, 141, 145), (191, 191, 191)]`